# How to use translation:update in symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, translation

I have some bundles in a Symfony2 project and I'm running the "translation:update" command to update the translation file for my bundle. While most of the parts works well and get the appropriate names, I don't seem to do the same for the form fields in the view files. Every time I run the command, I get back only the field name and not the full path I want them to have. For example e.g. I get *fieldname* instead of Mybyndle.formlabel.*fieldname*. I use the label option in the form builder in order for them to have the appropriate name as key and indeed the name changes when I see the form. But when I update the translation file, the entry in the file is only the field name.

What should I add to my code so that the translation sequence uses the correct format?

EDIT:
This an example:

- address.documentnumber.list: __address.documentnumber.list
- address.documentnumber.new: __address.documentnumber.new
- documentnumber: __documentnumber
- issuingAuthority: __issuingAuthority
- documentType: __documentType

The two first lines are from some tables and have the correct names.
The other three are the entity field names (?), because they are used as headers in the list and as form field labels in the "add new document" form.

What I want is to add a prefix name like "address.formlabel." in the entity fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`translation:update` wouldn't collect translation messages that used in PHP files(`controller` and `forms`).

I suggest to use **[jms translation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle)**, that can collect all translation messages from any place (`forms`, `controllers`, `templates`, `validations`)

Comment: I tried the JMS Translation bundle but it pretty much extracted what I was already extracting with translation:update. My problem is that I get some "orphan" entries that must be either from the entity or the form builder because the names correspond to entity fields. I'm looking for a way to give them a better, more appropriate name.

Comment: @John Krit, can you explain your problem with a example

Comment: I have just added an example. Look above.

Answer (score 0):

> translation:update wouldn't collect translation messages that used in
>   PHP files(controller and forms).

Now, since Symfony 4.3 this feature is available, your comment is no longer relevant for new release. So you should prefer this official tool than JMS Translation.

The feature is here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/30120

The documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#extracting-translation-contents-and-updating-catalogs-automatically